# How to connect to remote FTP server and upload an image file to it at specific location using PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, image-uploading, remote-server

I'm a newbie to advanced PHP. I'm using **PHP 5.5.18** for my website.

The scenario is, I have one remote FTP server. I want to get connect to it, upload an image file at specific location on that FTP server, save the file in that folder on FTP server.

I've successfully written a code to upload the image file to the same server from which I'm executing the PHP script. It's working absolutely fine for me.

But now I've to connect to some other remote FTP server and upload an image file to it. This is a completely new thing for me. I'm totally blank with this concept.

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Following is the working PHP code that I wrote to upload the file to the same server from which I'm running the PHP script.

```
<?php
  $target_dir = "uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
      echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
      $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
      echo "File is not an image.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }
  }
  // Check if file already exists
  if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Check file size
  if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Allow certain file formats
  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  } else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
      echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }
?>
```

Following are the sample representative credentials of my FTP server:

```
IP: 54.220.3.82
Username: myservercreds
Password: MyServerCreds
```

I tried to connect to this server using **FileZilla FTP client** by entering these creds and putting port number as **21**. Now I've to do the same thing using PHP code.

**I want to store this uploaded image file to the folder named "Images". This folder should have all the permissions(read,write and delete). If the folder is already present please don't recreate it.**

Comment: Web image upload and FTP operations are very different - do you want your script to do both? Have [a look here](https://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to see examples of FTP operations done programmatically.

Comment: @halfer:The server where I'm going to upload image is FTP server. I only want to establish a connection to that server in order to upload the image, do uploading the image and get disconnect from it. That's it. I've done the code for uploading the image to the same server so I did neither need to establish connection to it nor I need to disconnect from it. I might be saying something wrong, please forgive me. But this is what my concern is.

Comment: OK. I would stick with your local upload (uploads to same server) and then run a scheduled script to FTP the files to the other folder. You can do it immediately, but FTP can be quite slow, and you don't want to keep the user waiting longer than the time taken to upload locally. (That said, an FTP op server to server should be much faster). Have a look at the examples I provided?

Comment: (I didn't understand your point about connecting/disconnecting - that sounds like something you will have to do with FTP).

Comment: @halfer:See let me make the things simple for you. First of all forget about all things like FTP server, connect and disconnect. I want to upload the image to some other server having the credentials I mentioned(I used these credentials in FileZilla to connect to it manually.) in my question. Then check whether the folder "Images" exist there or not. If not create a new one and then add the image or if exist just add the image, don't create a new folder. That's it. Now is that clear to you?

Comment: If you want to do this in the context of a web application, you will need to upload it locally first (I'm assuming you know that already, since you've written that code). You _could_ post directly to the FTP server, if it is also a web server, and then redirect back to the first server, but cookies won't survive, and this approach is rather messy.

Comment: Were you looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php ?

Comment: @halfer:Actually I don't want to upload the image to my local server. It doesn't matter to me how much time it takes to upload image to some other remote server but I have to upload the image directly to the remote server only. The one remote server whose credentials I've given. All this should happen with PHP code. How to make this happen is my concern.

Comment: Righto. You want to do the connection using your PHP installation locally? You can't use your browser (unless you do the messy solution I outlined earlier). See the two links you've been provided above: you'll need to connect, send, disconnect. The manual will have examples for all of these.

Comment: @halfer:You provided me only one link. The link to manual.

Comment: Yes, it is a good resource. And @CEP provided the other one, where there is a full script to FTP a file programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to upload the file to a remote FTP server after you have saved it locally.

Say you have saved the file locally, with the path `$target_file`, like in your code. Now you can do something like this:

```
<?php

$remote_file = "images/" . $target_file;  // since you want to upload to a directory called "images".

$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.foo.bar") or die("Error in FTP connection");  // the FTP server you want to connect to.
$login_status = ftp_login($conn_id, "Username", "PaSswoRd") or die("Error in FTP login");  // Login to the FTP server.

// Now go ahead, and upload the file.
$upload_status = ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $target_file, FTP_BINARY);

if (!$upload_status)
{
    // do whatever it is that you want to do when you are unable to upload the file.
}

// Close the FTP connection after you are done.
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

This is, ofcourse, assuming that you have a directory called `images/` in your FTP server. If you don't, you can create it using an FTP client, or with PHP itself using

```
ftp_mkdir($conn_id, "images");
```

---

#### Notes:

- You can set permissions using the `ftp_chmod()` method.
- If you don't want the files on your server after uploading them, you can delete them with [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

  A better solution might be to just upload the withgout saving it locally. Just use `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']` where you use `$target_file` in the above example. And don't save the uploaded file using `move_uploaded_file()`, like in your code.
- Everything that you probably need, is probably in the documentation. Do take a look. *Docs* as not as scary as they sound. *Pun intended :)*.

  Documentation for FTP functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php

Hope that helps `:-)`

---

**Edit:** Thanks to @halfer for his comments on the question.